# How to pass rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I am trying to create the game Mastermind using test-driven development. I am having issues figuring out how to pass this specific test:

```
it "should valiate secret contains four accepted uppercase characters" do
            @game.secret = "XXXX"
            secret = "RRRR"
            valid1 = @game.checksecret(secret)
            valid2 = check_valid(secret)
            valid1.should == valid2 && @game.secret.should == secret && valid1.should == 0
end
```

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
def checksecret(secret)
        secret = "RRRR"
        valid1 = secret
        valid2 = check_valid(secret)
        valid1.should == valid2 && secret.should == secret && valid1.should == 0
end
```

This is the error message I get.

```
1) OXs_Game::Game#Mastermind game should valiate secret contains four accepted uppercase characters
 Failure/Error: @game.secret = secret

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `secret=' for nil:NilClass
 # ./wad_mastermind_spec_01.rb:13:in `check_valid'
 # ./wad_mastermind_gen_01.rb:61:in `checksecret'
 # ./wad_mastermind_spec_01.rb:92:in `block (3 levels) in <module:OXs_Game>'
```

I feel like I am trying to solve it the wrong way but can't figure out how I should be solving the problem.

Comment: your `@game` variable is nil

Comment: Make sure to set `@game`

Comment: @tibsar I have set `@game as @game = Game.new(@input, @output)`

Comment: @AlexChase where you set `@game` in the code?

Comment: @idej in the spec file

Comment: Use `pry` to make sure that `@game` is getting set

Comment: Try moving this line `@game = Game.new(@input, @output)` inside `it` block.